# AddListener to an Actor one time only

Tags: libgdx, scene2d

Is it possible to allow the user to touch an actor only one time. 
I've tried using boolean but the problem is I write addListener in the class constructor and I want it to be here not in a separate method

Comment: What about a boolean property in your class that would be checked in the beginning of the listener code and set to true after it fires for the first time?

Comment: what I've done is like that :


boolean hasTouched = false;

class MyActor() {
if (hasTouched == false) {
addListener...... 
        hasTouched = true;
}
}

Can you give me an example for what you are saying ?

Comment: I was thinking about something like this: class MyActor() { boolean hasTouched = false;  addListener {if (hasTouched == false)  {do something here... hasTouched = true; } } }. So the listener will trigger every time, but the logic you put inside it will be executed only once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you can remove the listener like this, I have not tested it though and no time for it right now.

```
final Table t = new Table();
t.addListener(ClickListener listener = new ClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void clicked(InputEvent event, float x, float y) {
        super.clicked(event, x, y);
        //Do stuff
        //...

        //remove this listener
        t.removeListener(this);
    }
});
```